# Using compose with Ramda in typescript and got issues

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I'm trying to use ramda with typescript but i've run into a type issue, especially when using compose.
Here are the dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/ramda": "^0.25.21",
  "typescript": "^2.8.1",
},
"dependencies": {
  "ramda": "^0.25.0"
},
```

and here is the code:

```
import { curry, compose, reject, isNil, tail } from 'ramda'

const arrayToObj = curry((props: string[], array: any[]): Record<string, any> => {
  const len = props.length
  const result: Record<string, any> = {}
  if (len > array.length) throw "TODO: arrayToObj not mathcing size"
  for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) result[props[i]] = array[i]
  return result
})

const matchRegExp = curry((
  pattern: RegExp, part: string
) => part.match(pattern))


const partToMatch = matchRegExp(new RegExp([
  /^\s*/,                           // skip spaces at begin
  /([TJQKA2-9]{2})([so])?/,         // first two cards
  /(?:-([TJQKA2-9]{1,2})([so])?)?/, // Extender
  /([-+*/])?/,                      // Expander
  /(?:\(([1-9]\d?)(%)?\))?/,        // Shrinker
].map(r => r.source).join(''), 'i'))

const matchToObject = arrayToObj([
  'x', 'group0', 'flag0',
  'group1', 'flag1', 'exp', 'shrink', 'percent'
])

const partToObject = compose(
  reject(isNil),
  matchToObject,
  tail,
  partToMatch
)
```

I get a type error within compose using tail telling me the List: `List: ReadonlyArray<T>` is incompatible with the `x: string` (coming from the definition of `compose`).
If I remove the tail everything is working. I've tried to cast the output of `matchRegExp` to `string[]` but it made no difference. I know that without casting `matchRegExp` returns a `RegExpMatchArray` but it raises no issue when it's plugin without tail to the `matchToObject` function. It puzzles me, and if someone understands why I do get this error, I would really appreciate.

While trying to resolve, I tried to insert the `compose` before the `tail` to plug the `Array.from` method but got this error `from is not defined in type 'ArrayConstructor'`. I guess it's another question, but that again puzzles me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Typescript typings, but removing them here, I get this to work by removing the `x` property in `arrayToObject`, converting

```
'9Qs-To*(30%)'
```

to this

```
{
  exp: '*',
  flag0: 's',
  flag1: 'o',
  group0: '9Q',
  group1: 'T',
  percent: '%',
  shrink: '30'
}
```

Not that I have any idea what this means (beyond have some relationship to playing cards!)

Is the `x` property left over to hold initial spaces from before you added `tail`?

BTW, I really like your technique of simulating multi-line regexes in Javascript.  I haven't seen that before.